# How to solve "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" problem?

Tags: angular, blur-admin

i am given a project to do, trying to use "blur-admin". But i couldnt get it run on my computer.
when i write "gulp serve" , it gives me error. I tried to add "npm-shrinkwrap.json" in same folder as package.json, and added "resolutions": {
"graceful-fs": "^4.2.4"  and  scripts": {
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
"postinstall": "bower install"   but nothing works.

Comment: Well, what code attempts to access a 'primordials' variable, and does the code properly import required modules and/or use the specified dependency versions? Adding packages only makes modules available to import.

Comment: @user2864740 thank you for answering. But i dont know how to answer. I am given a project that includes javascript files and stuff. The boss said i should use BlurAdmin, so i need to use angular 1, for solving an issue which the boss told me about. But i cant run it since i get a primordials error. I am totally new at this, i just try to get what i can do

Comment: Tip: you can answer your own question (see below) and accept it. This lets others know there was a resolution (or answer), and what it was.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I didnt know that, now i am going for it @user2864740

Answer (score 1):

I was using gulp 3.9.1, and node 14.16.0 But they were not compatible. So I deleted the node, and downloaded v10.24.0 Now it works.
If i want to use upper version of node.js, as I searched I should use gulp version of 4, below won't work.